# Manage distribution of container threads to avoid session timeout

Tags: java, http, session, tomcat, servlets

I have a webApp deployed on a Gateway server which is actually a reverse proxy for an upstream server. The gateway receives `HTTP` requests from clients and also from the upstream server.The upstream server keeps sending requests periodically. The requests of client are serialized and written in the response  to upstream server. The gateway server is Apache tomcat and has 200 threads by default. An `HTTP session` is created for the upstream server, at the gateway. If client sends 200 requests, all threads of the gateway are occupied and the requests of upstream server get rejected. The session times out and client receives error response - `HTTP 503`.
I do not wish to change the default server thread pool size. 
I can either reject client requests after they reach some specified max count, or I can use two  different thread pools by creating two different ports (`connectors` in case of tomcat). Is there anything else I can do?
thanks in advance.